# Laying over function onto scatter plot in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I would like to add the red line:

[image]

I am trying to add a function to lay over my scatter plot I have made, ideally to have an output similar to in the picture which has a red line scribbled on it. How am I able to add a function within my scatter plot (such as one in the form of y=C/ln(x) )? I will tweak around with the constants to try and get it to match similar to the rest line roughly drawn within the image.

Here is my current code in which the x and y values are from a table of collected data-

```
View(DataCollection)
plot(x=DataCollection$`x`, y= DataCollection$`y`,
     xlab = "x",
     ylab = "y",
     xlim = c(0, 2000),
     ylim = c(0, 100),
     pch=20,
     cex=0.2,
     main = "y against x",
)
```

Comment: @DAveArmstrong has posted a `ggplot2`answer. The answer within the `base`-plot system is the function `curve`.

Answer (score 1):

The code below would estimate the appropriate `C` term because `y=C/log(x)` would be the same as `y=C*(1/log(x))`, which you could estimate with OLS.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(519)
x <- c(runif(90, 10,100), runif(10, 100, 2000))
y <- 2/log(x) + rnorm(100, 0, .05)
dat <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y ~ I(1/log(x))-1, col="red", se=FALSE) + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you want to set the value of `C` directly, you could do so below by setting `const`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
const <- 2
set.seed(519)
x <- c(runif(90, 10,100), runif(10, 100, 2000))
y <- 2/log(x) + rnorm(100, 0, .05)
dat <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
dat <- dat[order(dat$x), ]
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_function(fun = ~const/log(.x), col="red") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>